# MySQL - max summary by month

Tags: mysql

I have this entity:

```
payments(idPayment, idGroup, price, paymentDate)
```

and I would like to find out max month (recordable month). I have max price, but month is wrong.

```
Select Max(x.price), x.month, x.year from(
   SELECT SUM(price) as price, Year(paymensDate) as year, Month(paymentDate) as month FROM `payments` 
   where idGroup=27 group by Year(paymentDate), Month(paymentDate)
) as x
```

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to pick the row with highest price amount

```
SELECT SUM(price) as price, 
       YEAR(paymensDate) as year, 
       MONTH(paymentDate) as month 
FROM `payments` 
WHERE idGroup=27 
GROUP BY YEAR(paymentDate), 
         MONTH(paymentDate)
ORDER BY price DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

`MAX` will give the max value for provided column but other values of column are not guaranteed to return the same values from that row which is picked by max